# roster.createEntry throws internal server error (500) exception

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, asmack

I am trying to create a XMPP chat client using aSmack library for android.I am using openfire server that runs on localhost.
I am creating a XMPPConnection and logging in the user successfully but when I try to create a new roster entry for that connection it throws an internal server error

```
Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.subscribe);
            presence.setTo(requestedUser);
            connection.sendPacket(presence);

            try {
                roster.createEntry(requestedUser+"@123", "nickname", null);

            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                Log.e("exception", e.getMessage().toString());
            }
```

Through this piece of code I am trying to send a friend request to another user.

Comment: Can you add some more information like the complete LogCat output and how you retrieved your roster?

Answer (score -1):

When you call `roster.createEntry()`, it will send request to your openfire server，and then the server will insert an new record into your **ofRoster** table in openfire database.
So insure that **ofRoster** table exists.